# Ajax calls and securing .js file information

Tags: php, javascript, security

Not so much a programming language... I'm building a website with many jQuery Ajax calls, not just to load data but also to perform many actions in my website, including admin specific actions like attributing groups to users, block user access, etc...

I don't do any user validation via js, my ajax requests get treated by PHP, so for all of these admin actions I firstly make sure that the user is in fact an admin (I check session/database information for this), I think this is the right way to go, but there is one thing that has been bugging me...

Consider this, my admin.php references an external .js file with all these Ajax calls, a common user doesn't have access to the admin page, but they can very well navigate to my js folder and see my admin.php AJAX scripts, these scripts have of course sensitive information in the parameters, stuff like the URL, the type (POST/GET). I trust (to an extent of course, security is a *big deal*) my PHP code to secure my application, but it still kinda... *grinds my gears*... that people know my URLs and what type of calls I make.

Maybe I'm just paranoid, if my code is safe why should I care if people see this information? (although declaring something as SAFE in web development should be the definition of 'cocky'), either way, this is what I considered:

- Not using external files on my admin pages, but it makes things not so well organized... I like to separate HTML from JS/PHP/etc
- Some sort of .htaccess-fu? Denying access to my js folder ultimately breaks functionality, so maybe someone out there has a better idea?
- Compressing my js files (with http://jscompress.com/ or similar), isn't really a solution, but it makes things harder to read

Any input on this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does denying access to your js folder break functionality?
You can keep the files accessible, but make sure they can't list contents, which already forces people to "guess" for your filenames.

Other than that, I honestly don't see any problem with them being able to deduct the calls you make.

As long as your calls are secured in your php back-end, this shouldn't really give you any trouble.

Furthermore, minifying is a great way to abstract your visible code, but calls will always be easily sniffed out with firebug or Fiddler.

Comment: I totally agree. By the way, widely used systems such as phpBB, Wordpress, Drupal, etc. have AJAX calls and URLs are publicly available in code... Security has to be handled on the server side.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Additionally, implementing security around your JS files just adds additional overhead to your server. You'd see much greater benefits by taking that overhead and applying it towards additional security checks and strengthening your authorization system.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I think I will end up just using 'Options -Indexes' in my htaccess, I think my code is mostly safe... but this gives me some peace of mind.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, users should not be able to browse your js files without knowing their exact name. Have you disabled the "Indexes" option in httpd ?

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the JS files to unauthenticated users, you could rename the .JS file to something random, like '2a2b1a82.js'. Then create some very silly PHP file, which just checks the users session, and if access is granted, does a readfile on '2a2b1a82.js':

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['login'] == true) {
  header('content-type: text/javascript');
  readfile('2a2b1a82.js');
}
?>
```

But besides that, your security should not depend of the access to some javascript files. As you stated, checking the users session in the PHP files which are called by the javascript files should be enough.

Comment: Sure it's dirty, but I think it's the only way of 'hiding' javascript files for unauthorized users. (if you would like to do this for some reason or another)

Comment: There is no reason to hide them if server-side security is fine. Don't worry, I understood what you meant :)

Answer (score 0):

There's other way around here. I don't know if you are familiar with Wordpress or not. There's  a separate php file written to process ajax requests. To that file, you need to pass params. There's one extra param you'd send that is called `nounce`. A nounce is generated per session. If nounce is valid then you'd find out which request is made like an action/ajax-url.

All you need to do is call this special php file, create unqiue nounce per user, pass params. Check nounce and proceed with actions.

Even if unwanted users can see this special file, they can not guess how the nounce are created.

Answer (score 0):

well first of all just thinking of "securing via obfuscation" is never a good idea, because it only pretends to safety.

To be clear i don't want to tell you that you should not hide your js files, by turning of Directory Listing. But you should put more energy in checking if your code is really save instead in obfuscating to much.

Obfuscating (depending in how much you do it and in which way) can cause that the code is harder to maintain and therefore is more prone to errors.

One important thing to do is, that you don't place php files or configuration files (where passwords are stored) in the root path your domain points to. (they should not be reachable via url). you should only have one entry file that includes your *bootstrap* php file. and using e.g. RewriteRules in your `.htaccess` file to redirect to the one entry point.

something structured like this:

```
project/scripts/
project/scripts/bootstrap.php
project/config/
project/logs/
project/public/  <---- //that is where http[s]://doamin.tld/ points to
project/public/index.php
```

the `project/public/index.php` will include  the `project/scripts/bootstrap.php` and there your code logic takes place.

this will make sure that even if for some reason the config file of your server get screwed up and sends the content of the `.php` files instead of executing the script, the visitor will only see the include to the file which is out of his reach. (or another example is the php `?-s` bug of the cgi module that allowed to see the source of each php file that was reachable by url)

Another thing you could think of is that you use php-fpm where you can run php as another user then the webserver, and make the php files only be readable by php.

The other importent thing you should think over is if you ajax calls are really secured. e.g. for actions like deleting, modifying or creating data, a simple check for the session cookie would not help against attacks that are based on that a user who is currently logged in is brought to an malicious site.